# How do I ensure keys of a key-value mapping are unique in SHACL?

Tags: shacl

Suppose my data models a key-value-mapping, for example, I run a fancy hotel and want to keep track of my guests' orders for every meal. How do I ensure that for each meal, I get **every guest's order** (i.e. all keys are present) and per guest I **only have one** order (i.e. all keys are unique)?

Example code to get us started:

Shapes:

```
ex:MealShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass ex:Meal ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path ex:orders ;
        sh:minCount 2 ;
        sh:maxCount 2 ;
        sh:node ex:OrderShape ;
    ] .

ex:OrderShape
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass ex:Order ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path ex:guest ;
        # The guest list! Code maintenance should happen here.
        sh:in ( "James" "Margaret" ) ;
        sh:minCount 1 ;
        sh:maxCount 1 ;
    ] ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path ex:order ;
        sh:datatype xsd:string ;
        sh:minCount 1 ;
        sh:maxCount 1 ;
    ] .
```

Data:

```
## Guests
ex:james ex:name "James" .
ex:margaret ex:name "Margaret" .

## Meals
### Valid meal
ex:breakfast
    a ex:Meal ;
    ex:orders [ ex:guest "James" ; ex:order "Eggs" ] ;
    ex:orders [ ex:guest "Margaret" ; ex:order "Cereal" ] .

### DESIRED TO BE invalid meal
### currently does not cause a validation result
ex:lunch
    a ex:Meal ;
    ex:orders [ ex:guest "James" ; ex:order "Salad" ] ;
    # Problem: James placed two orders, Maggie placed zero
    ex:orders [ ex:guest "James" ; ex:order "Burger" ] .
```

One solution I am aware of is to use qualifiedShape and its minCount and maxCount constraints separately for each key in the list. However, for larger "guest lists" this becomes hard to maintain. In my work, I have a list of roughly 40 keys. With 40 blocks of qualifiedShape statements, it becomes impractical to inspect the list (and I have already scripted the generation of those statements in the first place).

I have searched the documentation but could not find a kind of "sh:disjointInScope" or "sh:uniqueFromList" statement I wanted (crucially, the constraint should not force the value to be unique in the entire data graph, since e.g. James might appear in several orders). How do I get the desired behavior in human-readable SHACL code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your particular scenario correctly, then this should give you the violation:

```
ex:MealShape
  sh:property [
      sh:path ( ex:orders ex:guest ) ;
      sh:maxCount 2 ;
      sh:minCount 2 ;
  ] ...
```

The mechanism here is that a path expression (ex:orders/ex:guest in SPARQL notation) is used to state that there need to be exactly two distinct guests per Meal, which also implies that each of them can only be part of one order. Combined with the sh:in, this makes sure that only the allowed keys are present, and all of them. You need to however align the length of the sh:in list with the sh:min/max counts, so I am not sure how manageable that would be.

You can probably further generalize this pattern with the help of SHACL-SPARQL, e.g. to introduce the higher-level constraint components that you are talking about.